# Preserving large numbers when converting to characters in APL

Tags: apl

I have the following number in APL

```
1200000002341
```

When I do the following

```
k←1200000002341
k←⍕k
```

The value of k becomes 1.2E12.

How do I preserve the intricacies of the number when converting to character form?

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the exact APL implementation you are using. In Dyalog APL, the system variable `⎕PP` controls the precision. From the [docs](http://help.dyalog.com/17.1/#Language/System%20Functions/pp.htm):

> `⎕PP` is the number of significant digits in the display of numeric output. `⎕PP` may be assigned any integer value in the range 1 to 34.

For double-precision floating-point numbers (which is often the default for large numbers), the value of 17 is commonly used (which is enough to represent a double without precision loss).

```
      ⍕1200000002341
1.200000002E12
      ⎕PP←17
      ⍕1200000002341
1200000002341
```

Another way would be to convert the given number to an array of digits in base 10, and then convert each digit into string:

```
      ∊⍕¨10⊥⍣¯1⊢1200000002341
1200000002341
```

Read the code above as

- `10⊥⍣¯1` Convert to decimal digits
- `⍕¨` Stringify (convert number to string) each digit
- `∊` Enlist; flatten all (nested) items into a single vector

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which dialect of APL you're using.
Here's a simple (and perhaps hacky) way of doing it that should work on most:

```
k←1200000002341
n←⌈10⍟k+1       ⍝ number of digits in k
s←⍕(n⍴10)⊤k     ⍝ string
s←s~' '          ⍝ remove blanks
```